# Foundation 6 JS not working in Rails project

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

As title said i have problem with foundation 6 to get it working. I search everywhere and try every possible method to get it working but i still failed to do so.

I install foundation-rails gem and follow the instruction given properly but still not working. Css work fine the problem is i cannot switch the tab.

**Application.js**

```css
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .
$(document).foundation();
```

**Application.scss.sass**

```css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *=require foundation_and_overrides
@import "foundation_and_overrides"
```

And below is my **foundation_and_overide.scss**

```css
@charset 'utf-8';

@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';


// If you'd like to include motion-ui the foundation-rails gem comes prepackaged with it, uncomment the 3 @imports, if you are not using the gem you need to install the motion-ui sass package.
//
// @import 'motion-ui/motion-ui';

// We include everything by default.  To slim your CSS, remove components you don't use.

@include foundation-global-styles;
@include foundation-grid;
@include foundation-typography;
@include foundation-button;
@include foundation-forms;
@include foundation-visibility-classes;
@include foundation-float-classes;
@include foundation-accordion;
@include foundation-accordion-menu;
@include foundation-badge;
@include foundation-breadcrumbs;
@include foundation-button-group;
@include foundation-callout;
@include foundation-card;
@include foundation-close-button;
@include foundation-drilldown-menu;
@include foundation-dropdown;
@include foundation-dropdown-menu;
@include foundation-responsive-embed;
@include foundation-label;
@include foundation-media-object;
@include foundation-menu;
@include foundation-menu-icon;
@include foundation-off-canvas;
@include foundation-orbit;
@include foundation-pagination;
@include foundation-progress-bar;
@include foundation-slider;
@include foundation-sticky;
@include foundation-reveal;
@include foundation-switch;
@include foundation-table;
@include foundation-tabs;
@include foundation-thumbnail;
@include foundation-title-bar;
@include foundation-tooltip;
@include foundation-top-bar;

// If you'd like to include motion-ui the foundation-rails gem comes prepackaged with it, uncomment the 3 @imports, if you are not using the gem you need to install the motion-ui sass package.
//
// @include motion-ui-transitions;
// @include motion-ui-animations;
```

I hope someone can come with answer for this problem. I stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the foundation js conflict with jquery and turbolink.

## SOLUTION

create new file in app/assets/javascript/foundation.coffee

add this line of code :

```js
setup = ->

  $(document).foundation();

$ ->

  console.log "Loading page...!  " + Date.now()%10000

  setup()

  document.addEventListener "turbolinks:load", () ->

  console.log "turbolinks:load "  + Date.now()%10000

    setup()
```